# How to pass Smarty variable to PHP function?

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs, smarty3, smarty2

This is not a duplicate question, I couldn't solve my issue using answers from the other threads, besides my problem is different.

I'm trying to print a URL with an appended parameter using PHP in a Smarty plugin function. The software I use is WHMCS.

Below is a sample code of my function:

```
<?php 
/* 
 * Smarty plugin 
 * ------------------------------------------------------------- 
 * File:     function.aff.php 
 * Type:     function 
 * Name:     aff 
 * Purpose:  outputs a random magic answer 
 * ------------------------------------------------------------- 
 */ 
function smarty_function_aff($params, &$smarty) 
    { 
           $affiliateid = $params['affiliateid']; 
           $refflink = 'http://example.com/aff.php?aff=' . $affiliateid .''; 

           print $refflink; 
    } 
?>
```

In the template file, I use `{aff}` that supposed to print the whole URL including the appended parameter, however it prints the URL like that: `http://example.com/aff.php?aff=` as if the `$affiliateid` variable does not exist.

Now if I used the following `($affiliateid}` directly in the template file, it will output the user affiliate ID. But I need to use it in the PHP function above. Writing it directly in PHP as `$affiliateid` doesn't seem to work.

What I'm missing here? Any suggestions please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your function like this:

```
{aff affiliateid=$affiliateid}
```

See this link for more information: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/plugins.functions.tpl

It states:

> All attributes passed to template functions from the template are contained in the $params as an associative array.

an attribute (http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.attributes.tpl) is the `affiliateid=$affiliateid` part in my line of code above.

Comment: That is! Thank you so much, that worked. You cheered me up. Thank you once again.